# QT Creator _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL Miss match

Tags: qt, debugging, compilation, static-libraries, visual-studio-2010

I have linked my own static lib to my QT Creator project, the library has been compiled for both debug and release versions using VS 2010 Express. My QT Creator project uses VS 2010 compiler as well.

Now inside QT Creator whenever I try to build debug version of my project, I get multiple _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL link errors . What's more interesting the errors point to only those obj's that have some standard libraries included for example iostream or/and math .

When I build Release version of my QT Project everything is fine, and obviously if I un-link my library the debug version compiles fine as well .

Whats the proper way to compile my library so that I can use it inside QT Creator Debug mode ??

Many Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, interesting to know for me also. It is much easier to build under Linux whatever version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following to Your pro file:

```
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
    # debug
    LIBS += -lyour_lib_named
} else {
    # release
    LIBS += -lyour_lib_name
}
```